# Convert char* to int or float with error handling

Tags: c, string, floating-point, integer

I would like to convert a char* into an integer or double with error handling. Currently the functions I am using do not support error handling and do not give me any feedback on whether or not the string I gave to the functions was valid. Is there a way to do this in C?

```
int integer = atoi(str);
double flt = atof(str);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the string is inputted by the user and I would like to inform them if what they entered was valid/invalid

Comment: `strtol`, `strtod`.

Comment: [For atoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871711/atoi-how-to-identify-the-difference-between-zero-and-error).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5580975/1216776